# Tramp Scan Error

Tags: tramp

I'm getting the following error from tramp (v2.6.0.29.1) when I attempt `/-:|sudo::` and `tramp-save-ad-hoc-proxies` is true. I'm running this in a docker container in WSL2. I've tested it with my home directory both inside the docker container and on Windows. It's the same error either way. I also tried allowing it to put customizations in my init.el. I tried deleting the tramp and customizations files. I tried running `check-parens` on the customizations file it generates.

Depending on how I have things configured, it can become almost completely unresponsive. If I hit C-g a few times and wait 10-20 seconds, it will usually come back. Without `tramp-save-ad-hoc-proxies`, it seems to work fine. Any ideas?

```
Saving file /mnt/home/goldfita/.emacs.d/custom.el...
Wrote /mnt/home/goldfita/.emacs.d/custom.el
End of file during parsing: End of file during parsing, 
Scan error: "Scan error", "Containing expression ends prematurely XXX XXX"
Scan error: ...
```

Comment: What is your default method? When I run on my Fedora laptop `emacs -Q -l tramp --eval '(setq tramp-save-ad-hoc-proxies t)' '/-:|sudo::'` I get the error message `tramp-error: Method ‘scp’ is not supported for multi-hops.`.

Comment: I'm using ssh. I think I tried scp initially and it wasn't working, probably for the reason you just mentioned.

Comment: I see. Perhaps there's something odd in your init file. Please call `emacs -Q --eval '(setq tramp-default-method "ssh" tramp-save-ad-hoc-proxies t)' '/-:|sudo::'` - this works for me on Fedora.

Comment: I had to use `'/-:192.168.2.6|sudo::'`. It's refusing to write the customizations. `Setting 'tramp-default-proxies-alist' temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations.` I tried renaming my init.el, but I still get the same message.

Comment: No, that's expected. `-Q` doesn't touch the init files. I've asked you to run this command in order to know whether there is a general.

Comment: I believe we're at the end of SX help. We need further debugging, what's not possible here. Please write a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a Tramp issue. Fixed in Tramp 2.6.0.5 on GNU ELPA as well as in the upcoming Emacs 29.1.